# Build a matrix with values from a struct variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following tab-separated txt file:

```
User  Item    Rate
1       1       9
1       2       8
2       2       7
3       1       6
3       2       8
3       3       5
```

I import this to Matlab using *tdfread* which puts each column above in a corresponding variable of one struct (e.g., struct.user, struct.item, struct.rate). From there, I would like to build the matrix below without the use of loops:

```
9       8       NaN
NaN     7       NaN
6       8       5
```

Where each row represents one of the users above (from 1 to 3) and each column represents one of the items. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
i = struct.User;
j = struct.Item;
A = nan(3,3);
A(sub2ind(size(A),i,j)) = struct.rate;
```

Comment: You don't need the call to ONES. You can do this instead: `A = nan(3,3);`